# Angular unit test: Property subscribe does not have access type get

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Trying to run unit test of observable property when value comes with type error.

Running the test I get:
**Error: Property subscribe does not have access type get**

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for the help.

app-list.component.ts

```
export class TransferComponent {
    transfers$: Observable<Transfer[] | AppResponseError>;
    constructor(
    private transfersService: TransfersService) {
    this.transfers$ = this.transfersService.transfers$;
  }
}
```

app-list.component.spec.ts

```
it('should hide app-checklist component when return AppResponseError', () => {
    const error : AppResponseError = {
      code:'400',
      message:'Bad request'
    };    
    spyOnProperty(component.transfers$, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(of(error));
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-checklist'))).toBeNull();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1415#issuecomment-324493555):

> `spyOnProperty` is intended for use on objects that have used `Object.defineProperty` since that is implemented with a function behind it and can't be modified by just assigning to it. If you just have basic properties on an object, you should be able to just assign them.

You can just assign a stub value to `component.transfers$` property.

E.g.

`component.ts`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TransfersService } from './TransfersService';

export type AppResponseError = any;
type Transfer = any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transfer',
})
export class TransferComponent implements OnInit {
  transfers$: Observable<Transfer[] | AppResponseError>;
  constructor(private transfersService: TransfersService) {
    this.transfers$ = this.transfersService.transfers$;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.transfers$.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

`TransferService.ts`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TransfersService {
  transfers$ = of('real observable');
}
```

`component.test.ts`:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AppResponseError, TransferComponent } from './component';
import { TransfersService } from './TransfersService';

fdescribe('65208911', () => {
  let component: TransferComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TransferComponent>;
  const transfersServiceStub = {
    transfers$: of(),
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TransferComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: TransfersService, useValue: transfersServiceStub },
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TransferComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('should hide app-checklist component when return AppResponseError', () => {
    const error: AppResponseError = {
      code: '400',
      message: 'Bad request',
    };
    component.transfers$ = of(error);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-checklist'))).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
LOG: Object{code: '400', message: 'Bad request'}
Chrome 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 0 of 15 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
WARN: 'Spec '65208911 should hide app-checklist component when return AppResponseError' has no expectations.'
Chrome 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 0 of 15 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 1 of 15 (skipped 14) SUCCESS (0.086 secs / 0.026 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```